# Dynamic list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to know if python is able to create a list by comprehension using multiple and optional criteria.

Let's make an example. Considering the following object (partial description):

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = <next id of some kind>
        self.name = 'default name'
        self.gender = 'm'
        self.age = 20

<...>
```

Suppose I created a list of all `Person`s into `world`. Then I want to create a GUI which will allow me to browse the collection based on search criteria (the GUI conception is out of scope of the question), e.g name (regex based), id, gender and age (with equal, not equal and greater or lesser than). None of the search criteria are mandatory (we can suppose it's `None` I guess) and the type do not really matter for this question.

How can I filter the list of `Person` in a clever python-way?

If I have known criteria I could do a comprehension :

```
l = [person for person in world if re.search(person.name, '.*Smith') and person.gender = 'm' and person.age < 20]
```

But as the user is able to choose what he wants, I won't know what criteria to use. I can of course build this as fully fledged function:

```
l = world
if nameSearch:
    l = [person for person in l if re.search(person.name, nameSearch)]
if genderSearch:
    l = [person for person in l if gender == genderSearch]
<...>
return l
```

But I feel python would have a way to do it more properly.

Comment: As functions are first class citizens in Python, you could write a bunch of matcher functions, put them (dynamically) in a list and match against them in a single list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating my comment above:

As functions are first class citizens in Python, you could write a bunch of matcher functions, put them (dynamically) in a list and match against them in a single list comprehension.

Let `predicates` be a list of one-argument functions of type `Person -> bool`.

Then simply do:

```
[ pers for pers in world if all([f(pers) for f in predicates]) ]
```

Further exploring the functional route of thinking, you can create "dynamic matching functions" by creating functions returning matching functions:

```
def age_matcher(age):
    return lambda p: p.age > age
```

An `age_matcher(someAge)` can be added to your `predicates` array.

**Side note**

For these "database-search"-like tasks, you <s>will probably want to</s> really should look at libraries like [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), where you can make queries similar to SQL. You may be re-inventing a fairly complex type of wheel.

Comment: Pandas is a really good suggestion here, have a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: Panda lib seems definitely interesting. The idea of lambda is nice as well, I'm just not sure it can be applied for example to the age condition. Since you have the matching predicates lets say `==` that takes a Person as argument, but you how do you pass the number argument for the equality? I get that you can however do a `def isMasculine(person): return person.gender == 'm'` function and this would definitely work. Thanks

Comment: @M'vy You can, for example, create a function take an age threshold and returns an age matching function with that threshold. I'm adding it to my answer.

Comment: Might as well use a comprehension instead of the map and lambda: `all(f(pers) for f in predicates)`.

Comment: @YannVernier probably better, since I cannot make it work with the mapping.

Comment: There's a possibly significant difference between the comprehension with `[]` and without; with it you get a list, which means all predicates are evaluated, but without (or with parenthesis) you get a generator expression, which allows all() to shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Based DCS' comment, here is a example how to use functions as filters. A filter is just a function which returns a boolean (given an instance of `Person`). For faster processing I suggest you take a look at `pandas`, which is a very good choice for data filtering/sorting/munging, but this might get you started with a simple solution. The only task that is left to you, is to create the filters based on the user's input.

```
from random import random

class Person():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.name = 'Name{}'.format(id)
        self.gender = 'm' if random() > 0.5 else 'f'
        self.age = int(random() * 10) + 10

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person-{} ({}, {}. {})'.format(self.id,
                                               self.name,
                                               self.gender,
                                               self.age)
```

Setting up some test data:

```
people = [Person(id) for id in range(10)]

[Person-0 (Name0, f. 15),
 Person-1 (Name1, f. 14),
 Person-2 (Name2, f. 12),
 Person-3 (Name3, f. 18),
 Person-4 (Name4, m. 12),
 Person-5 (Name5, f. 18),
 Person-6 (Name6, f. 15),
 Person-7 (Name7, f. 15),
 Person-8 (Name8, f. 10),
 Person-9 (Name9, m. 16)]
```

Output:

```
def by_age(age):
    return lambda person: person.age == age

def by_name(name):
    return lambda person: re.search(person.name, name)

def by_gender(gender):
    return lambda person: person.gender == gender

filters = (by_age(15),
           by_gender('f'))

filtered_people = (p for p in people if all([f(p) for f in filters]))
list(filtered_people)
```

Which gives us the following filtered list of people:

```
[Person-0 (Name0, f. 15), Person-6 (Name6, f. 15), Person-7 (Name7, f. 15)]
```

You could even change the predicate `all` to `any` in order select all people which match *any* of the specified filters.

Comment: is there any benefit of creating a generator and then using a `list` method on it, instead of using a list comprehension directly?

Comment: `list` just realizes the generator for printing. I'm not a python expert, in this case you could certainly replace the generator expression with a list comprehension. I think the generator expression should be preferred whenever working with longer lists. In Python 3 a list comprehension `[...]` is only syntactic sugar for giving a generator expression to the list types constructor.

Comment: I should stop writing comments and write answers instead, I guess ;-)

Comment: @DCS I think point sharing would be an interesting addition to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
def search(self, condition):
    return filter(condition, self.l)


def search_re(self, **kwargs):
    filters = []
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
             value = re.compile(value)
             filters.append(lambda x: re.search(getattr(x, key), value))
        elif callable(value):
             filters.append(lambda x: value(getattr(x, key)))
        else:
             filters.append(lambda x: getattr(x, key) == value)
    def condition(person):
        return all(
                 f(person) for f in filters
               )

    return self.search(condition)
```

Usage:

```
persons.search(lambda x: x.name == "bla")

persons.search_re(name=".*Smith", gender="male")
```

Comment: That self.l is not defined above in the class, what was meant to be?